# Regarding Database on Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to store data directly to the database without having the user input something in it. I am planning on creating a school updater which updates students regarding school news and such. What confuses me is that how can I store data directly into it. Im not that good on servers so Im resorting into databases but Im confused where to start.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to store data in a remote database? If yes, you may want to use REST-APIs/Webservices and process the data on the remoteserver.

You should not (except Databases like CouchDB) connect your device directly to any remote remote device for security reasons.

Anyway, you may create a local SQLite database on your device and synchronise the data using REST.

Comment: I would use firebase

Comment: Firebase is good solution. For local database use can use:
http://greenrobot.org/greendao/
http://ormlite.com/

Comment: beginner and using orm? I dont think this makes any sense ;-) Better learn using SQLite databases before using orm/database mappings.